# Normalizing graph edit distance to [0,1] (networkx)

Tags: graph, networkx, graph-theory, similarity, edit-distance

I want to have a normalized graph edit distance.
I'm using this function:
https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.similarity.graph_edit_distance.html#networkx.algorithms.similarity.graph_edit_distance

I'm trying to understand to graph_edit_distance function in order to be able to normalize it between 0 and 1 but I don't understand it fully.

For example:

```py
def compare_graphs(Ga, Gb):
    draw_graph(Ga)
    draw_graph(Gb)
    graph_edit_distance = nx.graph_edit_distance(Ga, Gb, node_match=lambda x,y : x==y)
    return graph_edit_distance

    compare_graphs(G1, G3)
```

Why is the graph_edit_distance = 4?

[image]

Graph construction:
Hey

```
e1 = [(1,2), (2,3)]
e3 = [(1,3), (3,1)]
G1 = nx.DiGraph()
G1.add_edges_from(e1)
G3 = nx.DiGraph()
G3.add_edges_from(e3)
```

The edit distance is measured by:

```
nx.graph_edit_distance(Ga, Gb, node_match=lambda x,y : x==y)
```

The difference from graph_edit_distance is that it relates to node indexes.

This is the output of optimize_edit_paths:

```
list(optimize_edit_paths(G1, G2, node_match, edge_match,
                        node_subst_cost, node_del_cost, node_ins_cost,
                        edge_subst_cost, edge_del_cost, edge_ins_cost,
                        upper_bound, True))
Out[3]: 
[([(1, 1), (2, None), (3, 3)],
  [((1, 2), None), ((2, 3), None), (None, (1, 3)), (None, (3, 1))],
  5.0),
 ([(1, 1), (2, 3), (3, None)],
  [((1, 2), (1, 3)), (None, (3, 1)), ((2, 3), None)],
  4.0)]
```

I know it should be the minimum sequence of node and edge edit operations transforming graph G1 to graph isomorphic to G2.

When I try to count, I get: 
1. Add node 2 to G3, 
2. Cancel e1=(1,3) from G3
3. Cancel e2=(3,1) from G3
4. Add e3 = (1,2) to G3
5. Add e4 = (2,3) to G3

graph_edit_distance = 5.

What am I missing?

Or alternatively, what can I do in order to normalize the distance I receive?

I thought about dividing by |V1| + |V2| + |E1| + |E2|, or dividing by max(|V1| + |E1|, |V2| + |E2|)) but I'm not sure.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give us the definitions of the two graphs?  I expect a distance of 3 (delete , and this is what my networkx returns.  So I think I've got the graphs wrong.  I see a path from 1 to 2 to 3 in one graph and edges in both directions between 1 and 3 in the other.  In this case, delete the 2->3 edge from the first graph, delete node 3, and add a 2->1 edge.  Then the two graphs are isomorphic (even though the labels aren't the same).

Comment: Hey, I've added details in the post. I measure the GED with relating different nodes:
nx.graph_edit_distance(Ga, Gb, node_match=lambda x,y : x==y)

Comment: I still expect a distance of 3.0, and that is what my copy and paste of your code provides with the graphs you've defined.  (and note - the function `node_match` you've chosen will return `True` for any pair of nodes which have no attributes - it doesn't check that the node names are the same).

Answer (score 1):

I know its old post but I am currently reading about GED and was willing to answer it for someone looking for it in future.

Graph edit distance is 4

Reason:

1 and 3 are connected using an undirected edge. While 1 and 2 are connected using directed edge. Now graph edit path will be :

1. Turn undirected edge to directed edge
2. Change 3 to 2 (substitution)
3. Add an edge to 2
4. Finally add a node to that edge

Answer (score 1):

The Graph Edit Distance is unbounded.  The more nodes you add to one graph, that the other graph doesn't have, the more edits you need to make them the same.  So, the GED can be arbitrarily large.

I haven't seen this proposed anywhere else, but I have an idea:

Instead of `GED(G1,G2)`, you can compute `GED(G1,G2)/[GED(G1,G0) + GED(G2,G0)]`,
where `G0` is the empty graph.

The situation is analogous to the difference between real numbers.

Imagine that I give you `|A-B|` and `|C-D|`.  They are not on the same footing.
E.g., you could have `A=1`, `B=2` and `C=1000`, `D=1001`.
The differences are equal, but the relative differences are very different.

To convey that, you would compute `|A-B|/(|A|+|B|)` instead of just `|A-B|`.
This is symmetric to a swapping of A and B, and it's a *relative* distance.
Since it's relative, it can be compared to the other relative distance: `|C-D|/(|C|+|D|).`  These relative distances are comparable, they're expressing a notion that is universal and applies to all pairs of numbers.

In summary, compute the *relative* GED, using `G0`, the null graph, like you would use 0 if you were measuring the relative distance between real numbers.